# jquery and event scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have 1 class html with various elements i want add a class new class in first element that scroll top reach the top ofos this elements, then when the scroll reach the second add in second too and so on. i tried this

```
var element = $(".element"); 
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            for(var i = 0; i < element.length;i++){
                if(scroll > element.eq(i)){
                    element.eq(i).addClass("newClass");
                }
   }
})
```

html piece

```
<div>
    <div class="element">
        <img src="img/image1" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <img src="img/image2" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <img src="img/image3" />
    </div>
</div>
```

but this line element.eq(i).addClass("newClass") dont work :) how i should to do

Comment: Could you add a sample piece of HTML that you are using with the above jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use

```
if(scroll > element.eq(i).offset().top - ($(window).height() / 2) ){
    element.eq(i).addClass("newClass");
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bmdLqxza/2/)

Comment: it are using the top of first elements just :( the add class work but it use just top from first element

Comment: @Ricardopatrickmarinhodesou see http://jsfiddle.net/bmdLqxza/ it works .. but if not works you should show your html code

Comment: @Ricardopatrickmarinhodesou code works http://jsfiddle.net/bmdLqxza/1/  .. dont forget to include jquery

Comment: but it is adding the class just when the div get in top of window. i want when the top scroll Y reaches top of element or the postion down of before element

Comment: @Ricardopatrickmarinhodesou updated with demo .. when scroll before a half height of a div addClass .. you can play around ($(window).height() / 2)  to be just $(window).height()   just try it